# Execute one command from user as root

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I want to execute command `whoami` from user for example user1 as root

I mean is it possible to write in terminal `whoami` (being on user1) and get root?

Comment: Is `sudo` (eg `sudo whoami`) what you're looking for? Otherwise you probably need to be a little more clear about your question...

Comment: Perhaps create an alias for whoami that calls "sudo whoami" ?

Comment: If you just need to fake to some process, that you are root, you can use `fakeroot`

Answer (score 0):

Copy `/usr/bin/whoami` to `/usr/bin/whoami2`.

Create a new `whoami`, `/usr/bin/whoami` and `chmod +x /usr/bin/whoami`

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# imposter /usr/bin/whoami
if [ $USER = user1 ]
then     
    echo root    
    exit 0 
fi

whoami2 
exit 0
```